# The image that I save on the server is corrupted Rails

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Good morning people, I am sending an image from android studio to my ruby on rails server but when opening the image it is damaged, it appears with the legend: "Try to open it externally to fix format problem", the image is sent as multipart with retrofit.

This is the code where I send it:

```
        val url = currentPhotoPath.split("/")
      
        val filePart: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "users[image_profile]", url[9], RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse(
                    "image/jpeg"
                ), fr
            )
        );
        val call: Call<UserResponse> = MyApiAdapter.getApiService().uploadImageProfile(
            token.toString(),
            id,
            filePart
        );
        call.enqueue(this);
```

this where I create the image:

```
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "profile_image",
        ".jpeg",
        storageDir,
    ).apply {
        currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
    }
```

I would very much appreciate your help please in case I am doing something wrong or I am missing something, the image I am trying to send is selected from the gallery.

Comment: All questions must be written in english

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: `url[9]` is that an arrays of actual urls? Is that what you are trying to send?